# Kill all files except some

Tags: vba, loops, delete-file

I'm trying to delete all files in a directory apart from 4 files. I know how to delete all except specific files using the code below, but I'm sure it could be improved. Is there a shortened command that I've not found?

```
Sub Kill_Files()
    Dim fname As String
    fname = Dir$(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.*")
    Do While Len(fname) > 0
        If Left(fname, 10) <> "AAAAAAAAAA" Then
            If Left(fname, 10) <> "BBBBBBBBBB" Then
                If Left(fname, 10) <> "CCCCCCCCCC" Then
                    If Left(fname, 10) <> "DDDDDDDDDD" Then
                        Kill fname
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        fname = Dir$
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Use [Continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801hyx6f.aspx)?

Comment: It can cause problems if you alter a collection of files (eg by deleting one or more of them) at the same time as you're looping over the collection.  A more robust approach is to first add the files to a collection (in your case you could just add the files to be deleted) and finally loop over the collection and operate on its contents.

Comment: If they are just 4 files has no sense to improve it, you could use select case, something like case "A" or "B" or "C" or "D" 'do nothing case else erease it

Comment: Copy the four files to a separate directory, delete the current directory, copy the fours files back in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the nested `IF`s by:-

```
Sub Kill_Files()
    Dim fname As String
    fname = Dir$(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.*")
    Do While Len(fname) > 0
        If Not (Left(fname, 10) = "AAAAAAAAAA" _
                Or Left(fname, 10) = "BBBBBBBBBB" _
                Or Left(fname, 10) = "CCCCCCCCCC" _
                Or Left(fname, 10) = "DDDDDDDDDD") Then
            MsgBox fname   '<-- change this back to a Kill to see the code in action
        End If
        fname = Dir$
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to consolidate your `If` statements, you could rewrite this `Sub` as:

```
Sub Kill_Files()
    Dim fname As String
    fname = Dir$(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.*")
    Do While Len(fname) > 0
        If Left(fname, 10) <> "AAAAAAAAAA" And Left(fname, 10) <> "BBBBBBBBBB" And Left(fname, 10) <> "CCCCCCCCCC" And Left(fname, 10) <> "DDDDDDDDDD" Then
            Kill fname
        End If
        fname = Dir$
    Loop
End Sub
```